# Security aspects of home dir encryption

Tags: security, password, encryption, home-directory, ecryptfs

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a security risk if a password can be reset easily?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/116841/is-there-a-security-risk-if-a-password-can-be-reset-easily)

Changing the login password will automatically make an encrypted home directory re-accessible, as PAM takes care that the ectual encryption key is available with the new password.

Doesn't this imply that someone who steals my laptop can simply boot it from another medium, like a DVD, change the user password and reboot the system from the native harddisk to get access to my nicely encrypted data? In other words, isn't the encryption actually only protecting against the most un-educated of thieves?